# Как бороться с одновременными запросами?

Tags: mysql

К примеру есть код:

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT ...");
$n = $db->num($q);

if($n >= 1) {
 $db->insert("...");
}
```

Если послать к примеру 8 одновременных запросов, то условие $n >= 1 игнорируется и плодиться много данных(insert). Слышал, что можно исправить какими-то защитами от ddos на nginx, но этот геморой мне не подходит, учитывая то, что у меня ещё сайт на хостинге.

Можно ли как-то другими способами решить? Пробывал ставить и проверять куки, но всё равно, всё обходится.

Тип таблиц - **MyISAM**

Comment: транзакции?

Comment: @KoVadim, не понял, Вы о чём?

Comment: есть такая штука, как блокирующие транзакции. [Здесь](http://codepress.ru/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B8/sql/mysql-repeatable-read.html) описывается похожая проблема.

Comment: @KoVadim, но для них придётся юзать тип таблиц InnoDB, а у меня MyISAM. Где-то читал, что innoDB хуже MyISAM. Или я не прав?

Comment: холивары, какой тип лучше - оставьте другим. Если бы какой то был сильно лучше/хуже, другой давно бы ушел в небытие.

А может у того, что insert вставляет есть уникальное поле? и можно по нему отсекать дубликаты.

Comment: @KoVadim, уникальных полей нет :( А вот как работать с транзакциями, я не понял. Погуглил, поюзал примеры и всё равно при одновременных запросах вставляется сразу несколько данных вместо одной. Не работает.   $db->query("SET autocommit=0"); 
  $db->query("START TRANSACTION"); $db->inser("..."); $db->query("COMMIT");

Comment: конечно не работает, так как в MyISAM нет транзакций. Может SELECT как то объединить с INSERT в один запрос?

Comment: @ModaL напрасно удалили следующий вопрос. тема интересная.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Yura Ivanov](/users/6117/yura-ivanov), Я решил этот вопрос созданием поля в таблице с уникальным ключем.

Answer (score 2):

По правилам высокой науки надо действительно использовать механизм изоляции транзакций, то есть чтобы запросы были изолированы друг от друга пока не завершится транзакция (то есть некая совокупность действий) - в данном случае `insert` и чтение `$n`, но для MySQL это возможно только на движке InnoDB, MуISAM в угоду производительности не поддерживает модель [ACID](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)

Я бы посоветовал попробовать механизма локинга таблиц: [LOCK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html) то есть "запираете" доступ на запись к таблице делаете запрос, читаете свой `$n` далее если необходимо вставляете запись и "отпускаете" таблицу. То есть если в это время будет параллельный запрос на вставку то вставка не произойдет.

Это конечно, не совсем транзакционный механизм, поскольку во время транзакций запирается запись, а не вся таблица - но тем не менее это что-то чем ничего.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, а Вы не можете подсказать http://pastebin.com/Qj6xdP0v, вот мои запросы, как в них добавить блокировку?

Comment: @ModaL 

>This paste has been removed!

Comment: все доступно. Просто скрыто от любопытных глаз. Просто внимательно посмотрите.